# unable to start libvirtd daemon as root user and normal user

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, unix

I am trying to start `libvirtd` daemon with following command.

```
systemctl enable --now libvirtd
```

As normal user, I am asked for authentication to manage system service or unit files.
So, I tried after `sudo` to root user. But I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory.
```

The `journalctl` log has the below log entry.

```
Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process :23881:25774397 ( system bus name :1.260, obj
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: What is the result of `systemctl cat libvirtd`? Did you check with `journalctl` what can be this problem?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I got this error:
Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process :23881:25774397 ( system bus name :1.260, obj

Comment: Add the errors,logs in the question

Comment: @RomeoNinov Added to the question